# I tried converting the limit to a_n form, but couldn't get anywhere. Please provide help.

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, factorial

Recall n!=n(n-1)(n-2)...3x2x1. Define the sequence {a<sub>n</sub>} by a<sub>n</sub>=n.(n!)<sup>$\frac{-1}{n}$</sup>. Note that the lim a<sub>n</sub>=e.

Find the value of $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}$ ln(2n+1).((2n+1)!)<sup>$\frac{-1}{2n+1}$</sup> + $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}$ ln(3n).((3n)!)<sup>$\frac{-1}{3n}$</sup>

I tried to convert the given limit equation $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}$ ln(2n+1).((2n+1)!)<sup>$\frac{-1}{2n+1}$</sup> + $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}$ ln(3n).((3n)!)<sup>$\frac{-1}{3n}$</sup> to  a<sub>n</sub>=e, but couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE, please use Mathjax for all mathematical expresions

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$\ln (n) \cdot (n!)^{-1/n} = \frac{\ln n}{n} \cdot n (n!)^{-1/n} = \frac{\ln (n)}{n} \cdot a_n$$
where both $\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ and $a_n$ have finite limits as $n\to\infty$. Thus
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln (n) \cdot (n!)^{-1/n} = \left( \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln (n)}{n} \right) \left( \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \right).$$
Now what happens if you substitute $n$ with some other expression, say $2k+1$ or $3k$, and then take $k \to \infty$?